# Options "skip" and "indent" not recognised in package parskip

Tags: parskip

I get the following error whenever I try to use the option "`skip`" in package `parskip`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `skip=10ptplus1pt' for package `parskip'.See the LaTeX manual 
or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `indent=40pt' for package `parskip'.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
```

Here's a minimal example, taken from the Overleaf website, where it works fine (in their LaTeX engine):

```
\documentclass{article}
% Choose a conveniently small page size
\usepackage[paperheight=18cm,paperwidth=14cm,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
% Load blindtext package for dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Load the parskip package with skip and indent options
\usepackage[skip=10pt plus1pt, indent=40pt]{parskip}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]\par % Use \par to force a new paragraph
\blindtext[1]

The value of \verb|\parindent| was set via the \texttt{indent} option, so it is now \texttt{\the\parindent}. The other values are:

\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\baselineskip| is \texttt{\the\baselineskip}
\item \verb|\parskip| was set via the \texttt{skip} option, so its value is \texttt{\the\parskip}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If I just use the package without options, like  `\usepackage[]{parskip}`, I get no errors.

Note that I'm using TexMaker as a LaTeX editor. I haven't really fiddled with environment variables and so on so I don't think I've changed anything important. Is there some other package that somehow breaks `parskip` (the package)?

Is there an alternative to `\package{parskip}`? I just want to shrink the space between paragraphs in my document.

Comment: you have not shown a log but presumably you have a old version of the package

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. The high-level interface of TexMaker (which seems to be itself based on MikTex, another interface) doesn't make it easy.

Comment: texmaker isn't involved that's just the editor, you will be using mikex or texlive tex distribution. You should be able to update the package in miktex in the miktex  console.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, via the miktex console... and now I have different errors. I call that progress, so I'll keep trying to get new errors and see where that gets me.